# How do you use html & css for conditional vertical wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new to html & css. I am wondering if it is possible to do this. I have not found a way so far. I want to arrange my elements in a column with wrapping like

```
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

However, I only want to wrap the elements if there is enough horizontal room to do so without a horizonal scrollbar. Otherwise, I want a vertical scroll bar and the items to be in a single column.

Comment: I think you'll need to use `display: grid` for that. CSS `display: flex` really doesn't handle multiple rows very well. Also, I understand that `flex-wrap` wasn't originally meant to exist at all because `flex` was only meant for 1-dimensional layout and `grid` for 2-dimensional layout, but adding `flex-wrap` was simple to implement and solved a lot of use-cases without the complexity of `grid`.

Comment: I was messing around with settings at w3schools tryit and found this works pretty good
`div {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}`

Comment: I think the `max-height: 100%` is the key. But is has to be in that order. max-height, direction, wrap

Comment: The syntactical order of distinct (and non-shorthand) properties in a CSS rule is not significant. If you're observing differences in behaviour with a different property order then something is _really wrong_ with your set-up.

Comment: I was wrong the flex settings were still orienting in a row not a column.

Comment: display: grid still renders the items left to right first instead of top down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a very similar question here [Flexbox using align-items: flex-start together with align-content: center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065278/flexbox-using-align-items-flex-start-together-with-align-content-center). The main difference between our questions is that I was working with row orientation.

Essentially, there is no way to dynamically detect "is there enough room". You have to tell the browser when there is or is not enough room.

So, media queries are your way to go.

You'll also see that I put a max-height in the CSS below. Somewhere in your markup, at some level, there is going to need to be a height constraint or the columns will not wrap.

I've setup a sandbox for you https://jsfiddle.net/w2rdbpo0/

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.flex-container > div {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  /* 600 pixels totally random  */
  /* just assuming 600px meets "enough horizontal room" requirement */
  
  .flex-container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .flex-container > div {
    max-width: 250px;
  }
}
```